Who gets credited with the turnover in basketball
A player throws a good pass to a teammate who loses it or doesn't catch the pass who is credited with the turnover?

Does this answer your question? How are individual turnovers determined on errant passes? I appreciate that's "good" vs "bad" passes but the answer still seems to be relevant.
